# Material parameter change callback in 3ds Max

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

I am creating a python script for 3ds Max, and I was searching for a way to create a callback when a Vray material is changed.
I am not used to max script, but while I was looking at the documentation I was able to create different callbacks using "callbacks" or "NodeEventCallback". It was not hard to create callbacks for node creation or opening materials in the SME window for example.
But I could not find any way to create callbacks when a material parameter is changed.
Apparently, there is no callback event name or return parameters on the documentation for that:

https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-C1F6495F-5831-4FC8-A00C-667C5F2EAE36

Does anybody know how to create a callback for every parameter change on a material?
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe start here: [Change Handlers and When Constructs](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-513285B3-DBF6-471E-B587-B5BE14D4D875)

Comment: Thanks @paddy! I was able to do that using maxscript. But since it uses "when", I am having a hard time to do it in python. Do you have any ideas? Here is the code in maxscript: "when parameters meditMaterials[1] changes obj do()"

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. I primarily work with the C++ SDK. Within that context, the general thing you wanna be intercepting is `REFMSG_CHANGE` which is a notification passed through the reference hierarchy. It seems the Python documentation isn't very complete, or Python support just isn't as rich as MAXScript. I have no idea whether you can access that within Python. Can you not just do the hooking with MAXScript and have that invoke your Python stuff?